# MFP and Worklight :: exclude Frameworks/sqlcipher.framework from SCM

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We've had to remove `i*/native/Frameworks/sqlcipher.framework` from our SCM repository due to size limitations.

Thankfully, we have found that the `mfp build` command re-creates it in local copies, so this works really well.

However, the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html) doesn't list `sqlcipher.framework` as ignorable - it states that the entire Frameworks directory should be checked in.

Can the documentation be updated to state `sqlcipher.framework` should not be checked in?

We've updated our [template .gitignore project](https://github.com/andrewferrier/mfp-gitignore) to allow for this on MFP 7.0, but it would be good to get official confirmation that this is "OK".

Answer (score 0):

I've created a documentation defect to have this corrected in the user documentation topic "Integrating with source control systems" in the Knowledge Center for IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3, 7.0 and future releases. Thanks.